# USB ports malfunction since Lubuntu 16:04 update

Tags: 16.04, usb, lubuntu

I am having a problem with certain USB devices not being recognised by the front USB connections on my system so that files cannot be read, which has got worse since an update to 16:04 from 14:04.
The behaviour varies from one port to another and with different devices, such that I am not even sure whether or not this is a physical fault with the USB connection. Significantly, a USB connection at rear works fine.
Behaviour is also inconsistent with my other dual boot OS, which is still XP SP3. My MSI Mobo is also a bit old. 
The devices I have trouble with are a Tascam DR-05 portable audio recorder, with SD, a Sony camera with SD, and a Moto G phone with internal HD store.

On connecting to either front USB port the Tascam audio recorder display reads “connected”  but the device is not shown in the PCMan file manager list of drives /file manager “places” and contents can't be accessed. Sometimes the computer monitor displays “D Bus error” while trying to connect.

On connecting the Sony camera to either front USB the device display occasionally flashes “connecting” but doesn't connect and similarly is not shown in the file manager list of drives.

My MotoG smartphone on connection to one USB port gives an error message on the computer “couldn't find matching udev device” window, flashing alternately with an“open in file manager” window, but device won't open. However, on the other USB port, it connects normally

*Significantly, all three devices connect normally via the USB ports on the motherboard at the rear of the computer case.*
The front ports are USB 2.0 but I don't know what the rear ones are.

For comparison, I can connect an external HDD to any USB port and it is recognised. 
Also, the Sony and Tascam connect properly to all ports if I use my Dual Boot XP OS, excepting only that the Sony camera sometimes flashes “not recognised” and has to be reconnected..

Before the update, all devices worked on the right hand socket only.
I have a new laptop with Windows 7 and all devices work normally on it.
Could anyone advise what would be the best way to get the front USB sockets working again?

Thank you for your interest, I have now edited in the lsusb results.
NB the detected logitech webcam C170 is not an issue at present

With nothing connected below:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c001 Logitech, Inc. N48/M-BB48/M-UK96A [FirstMouse Plus]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1631:5002 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1631:5400 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

With tascam connected to front left and right ports,  lsusb just causes a blank line in terminal,
but from a rear usb I get

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 058f:6335 Alcor Micro Corp. SD/MMC Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c001 Logitech, Inc. N48/M-BB48/M-UK96A [FirstMouse Plus]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1631:5002 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1631:5400 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Sony camera left and right front,

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c001 Logitech, Inc. N48/M-BB48/M-UK96A [FirstMouse Plus]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1631:5002 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1631:5400 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

which is the same as for nothing connected, although a while ago I was getting the camera to show in the usb list, no idea what is happening.

Anyway, Moto G front left below:

```
Bus 001 Device 034: ID 22b8:2e82 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c001 Logitech, Inc. N48/M-BB48/M-UK96A [FirstMouse Plus]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1631:5002 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1631:5400 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Front right below, but although this is the same, on the computer I can't connect from the right hand one, I just get a fast alternation of a "couldn't find matching udev", "unable to open usb device 001,078" and the standard "open file" window, which doesn't stay on screen long enough to work.

```
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 22b8:2e82 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:082b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C170
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c001 Logitech, Inc. N48/M-BB48/M-UK96A [FirstMouse Plus]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1631:5002 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1631:5400 Good Way Technology 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `lsusb` both before and after plugging in the problematic devices in question?

Comment: OK, edited to include lsusb lists. By the way, from this, could you help me identify which one of my physical usb ports is the 2.0? Would it be one of the two at front or the rear? Physically at rear I have four. The MSI guide book I have only states that I have JUSB1 and JUSB2 standard pin headers but I can't tell from "lsusb" which is which. Why are there 9 or 10 lines output when i only have 4 + 2 ports?